# Can you preface advance Where methods with OR in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent.

Can I preface any advance where method with an 'or'?

I know you can do with with a vanilla where: i.e. `orWhere(...)`

However what about the other where functions like `whereNotBetween()` can I simply use the method `orWhereNotBetween()` or will I have to use `whereRaw()` to implement this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. All where's I know of have an `or` version.

However here's how you can check for the future (instead of asking on SO):

- Do a full text search for the function name in the framework source (in your project)
- specifically look at the source of [`\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php) and search for the method name.

Comment: Thanks :) and thanks for the tip - it didn't even occur to me to do that :$

Comment: sorry I had to wait before I could accept it - done now!

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to make sure you don't forget it ;)